# GitkKraken crashes at startup most probably related to my nvidia graphics driver on Fedora 37

Tags: opengl, driver, nvidia, gitkraken

I'm running GitKraken 9.2 and since recently it started crashing when I tried to start GitKraken on my Fedora 37.

The crash dump and log seems that the crash is related to my graphics driver installation, which is.

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP107GL [Quadro P400] driver: nvidia v: 525.89.02
  Device-2: Dell Integrated_Webcam_5M_IR type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.20.14 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa dri: swrast
    gpu: nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch resolution: 1: 3440x1440~60Hz
    2: 2560x1440~60Hz 3: 2048x1152~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.7 renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
```

The GitKraken produced log looks like this:

```
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]: (node:8451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 2
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at handleError (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:110593)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at handleError.next (<anonymous>)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at next (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681523)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at proc (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681296)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at pe.<computed> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4676627)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at /usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681079
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at digestEffect (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4682151)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at next (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681588)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at Object.currCb [as cont] (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681913)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at end (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4680254)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at abort (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4679615)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at D.cont (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4679710)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at next (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681667)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at currCb (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681913)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at /usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4675225
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]: (node:8451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 7)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]: (node:8451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 2
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at handleError (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:110593)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at handleError.next (<anonymous>)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at next (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681523)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at proc (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681296)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at pe.<computed> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4676627)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at /usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681079
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at digestEffect (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4682151)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at next (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681588)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at Object.currCb [as cont] (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681913)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at end (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4680254)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at abort (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4679615)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at D.cont (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4679710)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at next (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681667)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at currCb (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4681913)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at /usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/src/main/static/main.bundle.js:2:4675225
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]:     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Mar 15 13:37:58 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]: (node:8451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)
Mar 15 13:37:59 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8451]: state:  checking
Mar 15 13:38:00 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8632]: (node:8632) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Mar 15 13:38:00 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8632]: (Use `exe --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Mar 15 13:38:00 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8632]: (node:8632) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated.
Mar 15 13:38:01 tag009442760151 gitkraken.desktop[8482]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After failing with lots of trial and error, such as updating the driver, changing the OpenGL renderer, etc. I finally stumbled upon GitKraken's launch options, which solved my problem.
The one option I used was for disabling hardware acceleration

```
$ gitkraken --disable-gpu
```

If this doesn't help for you, I've found two other options that may:

```
$ gitkraken --no-sandbox
```

or

```
$ gitkraken --disable-extensions
```

Good Luck!